# How to embed a mobile number with the external link

Tags: objective-c

How can i embed a mobile number with the external link using objective c.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *telephoneNumber = @"+123456789"
NSURL *target = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", telephoneNumber]] autorelease];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:target];
```

Did you mean such a case?

Comment: Hi, NR4TR, the string should be tel:// instead of tel:.                                                           NSURL *target = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", telephoneNumber]] autorelease];         please edit your answer.

Comment: Hi! Actually, "//" is not obligatory in that case, just have checked :) Thanks for being bothered